# DB2 Access Issue

Tags: linux, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper, db2-luw

I have installed my DB2 in VM - Linux. While i try to connect my SQL developer with DB2 from windows it gives the error. I have looked everywhere but but nothing on this. Please help. Attaching screenshot for reference.

[image]

following is the result of my db2level

```
DB21085I  Instance "gomobile" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL10010" with level identifier "0201010E".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v10.1.0.0", "s120403", "LINUXAMD64101", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1".
```

Comment: Search for SQL1639N.  Did you do a root-install of Db2?  If not, you need to use db2rfe. Follow the documentation at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0050569.html  .  Also you should give your Db2 version (the output of the db2level command).

Comment: i have added my results for db2level command

Comment: If you did a nonroot install, did you run db2rfe as suggested?  Beware of using fixpack0 of V10.1 at fixpack 0, too many bugs long since fixed. Consider either doing a root install of v10.1fixpack 6,  or better use V11.1.2.2.